# Oracle apex ords installation

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, memory, oracle-apex

I'm using Oracle 11g and Apex 18.1, Tomcat 9.0.4. During the installing of ords on step java -jar ords.war, below error is raised:

```
Enter the location to store configuration data: C:\ords\config
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.dbtools.jarcl.Entrypoint.invoke(Entrypoint.java:66)
        at oracle.dbtools.jarcl.Entrypoint.main(Entrypoint.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
....more
```

I have created a setenv.h file with following statements, but no luck!

```
CATALINA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
-server -Xms1536m -Xmx1536m
-XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/comment/16784351#Comment_16784351

> java -Xmx800m -jar ords.war